# Find missing filenames in sequence off numbers stored in a list

Tags: python

I have a string list of timestamp (date_millisecondtime.csv) based filenames like these:

```
    [..., file_20181105_110001.csv, file_20181105_120002.csv,    file_20181105_130002.csv, file_20181105_140002.csv,    file_20181105_150003.csv, file_20181105_160002.csv,    file_20181105_170002.csv, file_20181105_200002.csv,    
file_20181105_210002.csv, file_20181106_010002.csv, file_20181106_020002.csv, file_20181106_030002.csv...]
```

So here files with date 2018-11-05 (Nov 5, 2018) with timestamp 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 20 and 21.

I want to print only filenames 18 and 19 as they are missing. And the valid time range is from 1 - 23 so if hour in filenames are not present in this range for a given day (here its 2018-11-05), print those missing hours files.

Comment: One way to do it is to sequentially iterate through both of them (timestamp you want and filename) together. For that you will need to sort the list of filenames and have a (sorted) list of all timestamp you want. For the second input, you can pre-compute a list of interactively generate it. Afterwards, iterate through your list of Timestamp and check if the file exist. If the file exist, (do something) and move forward both the inputs. If doesnt exist a filename for that timestamp (do something when doesnt exist) and move forward Only the input with the timestamp.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to use a set comprehension to extract the times present. If I understand your requirement, you can then calculate the `min` and `max` times and take the difference from a `set` derived from a `range`:

```
L = ['file_20181105_110001.csv', 'file_20181105_120002.csv', 'file_20181105_130002.csv',
     'file_20181105_140002.csv', 'file_20181105_150003.csv', 'file_20181105_160002.csv',
     'file_20181105_170002.csv', 'file_20181105_200002.csv', 'file_20181105_210002.csv']

present = {int(i.rsplit('_', 1)[-1][:2]) for i in L}

min_time, max_time = min(present), max(present)

res = set(range(min_time, max_time)) - present  # {18, 19}
```

You can then build your filenames from the missing times. I'll leave this as an exercise [hint: list comprehension].

Answer (score 0):

Another solution in case you need to check also files missing at the beginning/end of the list (e.g: hour 0-10, 22 and 23)

```
filenames = ['file_20181105_110001.csv', 'file_20181105_120002.csv', 'file_20181105_150003.csv']
pos = 0
for h in range(0, 23):
    n = "file_20181105_" + str(h).zfill(2)
    if pos < len(filenames) and n == filenames[pos][: len(n)]:
        print("Found", h)
        pos += 1
    else: print("Not found", h)
```

Of course, you can build the `n` with the day you want to go through in multiple different ways. If needed, you can create another loop to go through days.

Edit:

If we want to check for more than one day, we can loop through the days checking its files/hours.

IMHO, i would suggest a lot of changes in the following code depending on the use case, number of days, number of file names, preference and code style, etc.

```
filenames = ['file_20181104_110001.csv', 'file_20181105_120002.csv', 'file_20181105_150003.csv']
pos = 0
missing = []
for d in (4, 5):
    for h in range(0, 23):
        n = "file_201811" + str(d).zfill(2) + "_" + str(h).zfill(2)
        if pos < len(filenames) and n == filenames[pos][: len(n)]:
            pos += 1
            print("Found", d, h)
        else:
            print("Not Found", d, h)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. When there is more than 1 date in the same list, assume sorted, I will have another for loop on top of it? How will that work? Like in my example, I have dates Nov 5 and Nov 6

Comment: Yes, you will need to loop outside this for the dates you want to check. I will update the answer with the for loop outside.